# kill process if it exceeds 6GB

Tags: batch-file

Currently on windows server, some process is running and it keeps on consuming memory. I want to kill the process if it exceeds specific limit e.g. process should be killed if it exceeds 6 GB memory usage. I'm looking for batch script which could be added to scheduled task. Any help on this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What do you consider as "memory use"? There is no single unambiguous definition, yet your script must use one definition.

Comment: In windows task manager, under "Memory" we see the usage. If the process exceeds specific memory, I want to kill that process.

Answer (score 4):

Kill process `java.exe` if memory usage more than `6Gb`

```
taskkill /F /FI "memusage gt 6144000000" /IM java.exe
```

Kill `any` process if them memory usage more than `6Gb`

```
taskkill /F /FI "memusage gt 6144000000"
```

PS: [Manual](https://www.windows-commandline.com/taskkill-kill-process/)

Comment: Wow. Never knew of that. Note a couple of additions to this answer (from 2014): at least in Windows 10, the memusage is in kb, so you'd use 3 fewer zeros above. Also, someone may wonder "what memory column in Task Manager does this relate to?" I can tell you from testing that seems to be "working set", not the others. Finally, of course you must be running the cmd line "as admin".

Comment: Correcting to my last comment (I could not edit it): I should have said that you must be running "as admin" to kill processes other than those started by YOU (such as to stop a process started as a Windows service).

Comment: I think taskkill (and tasklist), at least in Windows 7 and Windows 10 (where I've tested it), are not working with memusage where the threshold is above 4194303 (which is 2^22-1). So you cannot filter for processes with more than 4194304 kB of memory usage.

Comment: How did I find this number? Because I had a scheduled task to kill a process when the memory exceeded 20GB, but it was killing it at lower memory usage. So I started investigating with tasklist /FI memusage gt until I found that `tasklist /FI "memusage gt 4194303"` wasn't giving any process (as expected) while `tasklist /FI "memusage gt 4194304"` was giving **all** processes (making me suspect there is an integer overflow somewhere).

Comment: Makes sense, since 2^32 (the first integer to overflow 32-bit unsigned int) = 4194304 * 1024 (the number of bytes per KB)

Answer (score 2):

Some like this should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET procName=someProc.exe
SET RAMLimit=123.456
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('tasklist^|findstr %procName%') DO SET foundString=%%F
FOR /F "tokens=5" %%F IN ("%foundString%") DO SET RAMConsumption=%%F
IF %RAMConsumption% GEQ %RAMLimit% TASKKILL /IM %procName%
```

Comment: Great!What would be RAMLimit if 6GB would be limit?As per my understanding memory usage shown is in Kb. Right?Also if there are multiple processes of same name running, is it possible to kill specific process which consumes more memory based on PID? If possible could you please extend above code to handle it? Thanks for your help.!

Answer (score 0):

In Power Shell:

ps notepad |%{if($*.WorkingSet -gt 6000000000){kill -id $*.id -force}}

Kills the process 'notepad' which has about 6 GB of memory.
Tested on Windows 10, Windows Server 2019