# How to taskkill when process reaches specific memory?

Tags: memory, process, scheduled-tasks, taskkill

I'd like a batch file that checks a processes memory size and if over 100MB, it terminates it.

We have a process that runs on a server that when it reaches 130MB memory, it stops functioning and we taskkill it. It then automatically starts back up at 12MB memory and works fine for a few days to 2 weeks etc.

This is what I've been manually running:

taskkill /s HOSTNAME /F /T /IM "executable.exe" /FI "USERNAME eq NETWORK SERVICE"

It would be good if that taskkill command could be triggered as part of a scheduled task that first checks the memory size of the process.

EG: IF PROCESS_MEMORY > 100MB THEN TASKKILL PROCESS

Cheers

Comment: Hi, this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257686/kill-process-if-it-exceeds-6gb

Comment: That looks great IronMan - My only concern though is there are multiple instances of this executable running, but I only want to monitor and taskkill the one running under "NETWORK SERVICE".