# KIll a Process exceeding x GB Memory in Windows Server 2016 with bash (x > Int Range)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, taskkill

I'm trying to auto kill a process via batch script in Windows Server 2016. The process should be killed if the Memory usage of any process is above 12GB.

There is already a Version to kill processes below the maximum INT value: [kill process if it exceeds 6GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257686/kill-process-if-it-exceeds-6gb)

This does NOT work for bigger values than INT can handle. You can't kill a task bigger than 2,147,483,647 x 2.

So

```
taskkill /F /FI "MemUsage gt 12000000000"
```

results in

```
ERROR: The search filter cannot be recognized.
```

Any idea how to circumvent the (32-Bit) Limit in the MemUsage filter given by the Integer Range?

Taskkill documentation: https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html

Comment: Have you tried WMI: **WMIC.EXE Process WHERE (WorkingSetSize ^> 12000000000) CALL Terminate** ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. *See Comment from Daemon-5:*

```
WMIC.EXE Process WHERE (WorkingSetSize ^> 12000000000) CALL Terminate
```

Comment: Is this command resident in memory or do I have to run it every time I spot a memory consumption issue?